# g++ default parameters

Tags: c++, bash, compilation

While using compiler such g++ on command line, there are some parameters, which need to be given in all invocation of g++, and which are different from default parameters. Is there a way (e.g. using bashrc), so that my selected parameters canbe made default. I am compiling single files, so using makefile is not convenient.
I could not find exact answer anywhere among previuos answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you could put something like this in your `.bashrc` file:

```
alias g++='g++ -WHATEVER'
```

I'm personally not a big fan of this, because it could get confusing.  I would rather do something like this:

```
alias my_g++='g++ -WHATEVER'
```